# Finding total number of triplets that sum upto a certain value in C getting incorrect output?

Tags: c

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    system("cls");
    int count = 0;
    int arr[8] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
                if (arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k] == 12 && arr[i] != arr[j] && arr[j] != arr[k]) {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Count=%d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

My expected output is `6`. But I'm getting `36` as output.

When I change `j = i + 1`, and `k = j + 1`, the code works. But I'm not sure why it works. Mine code should also work as I've tested all possible conditions.

I understand why my code doesn't work it's because it produces below output:

```
1 3 8
1 4 7
1 5 6
1 6 5
1 7 4
1 8 3
2 3 7
2 4 6
2 6 4
2 7 3
3 1 8
3 2 7
3 4 5
3 5 4
3 7 2
3 8 1
4 1 7
4 2 6
4 3 5
4 5 3
4 6 2
4 7 1
5 1 6
5 3 4
5 4 3
5 6 1
6 1 5
6 2 4
6 4 2
6 5 1
7 1 4
7 2 3
7 3 2
7 4 1
8 1 3
8 3 1
```

Comment: And what output do you get?

Comment: You're counting the triple `(1, 3, 8)` but also `(3, 1, 8), (1, 8, 3), (3, 8, 1), (8, 1, 3), (8, 3, 1)`

Comment: As @cafce25 says, with  this implementation, you need to divide the result by 6 (3 factorial to be precise). With the condition `arr[i] != arr[j]...` you are eliminating duplicates in the resulting triplets even if there are duplicates in the input set. You may want to compare just the indices.

Comment: After your edit, you still kept the condition `arr[i] != arr[j] != arr[k]` which, as @derpirscher says, does not do what you expect (unless you expect it to check if `arr[i]` is 0 or 1 depending on the equality of `arr[j]`and `arr[k]`).

Comment: @derpirscher It's incorrect but it's not invalid. It's perfectly valid C code

Comment: @derpirscher It *is* a matter of words. "Invalid" would normally refer to something not complying with the rules of the C standard. E.g. `arr]i[`.

Comment: @nielsen dividing by 3! works, but why do that? Ig some permutation math is involved, can you give me a refresher?

Comment: @usedmoney, 3! is the number of permutations for a set of 3 elements. If you have 3 elements, you can choose 3 for the first position, 2 for the second position and 1 (the remaining element) for the last position, i.e. 3*2*1 possibilities. You can of course replace 3 with `n` for any positive integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of the long `if` statement you have

```
arr[i] != arr[j] != arr[k]
```

I guess you are trying to compare all 3 variables but that's not what the code does. Besides that you have already made that check with `arr[i] != arr[j] && arr[j] != arr[k] && arr[i] != arr[k]` so you don't need it.

That said, I find it strange that you check the values for being equal. I would expect that you should check the index, i.e. like `i != j && i != k && j != k`.

Anyway your code is also wrong because you start all three loops from zero. Starting all loops from zero causes the code to check the same triplet several times, i.e.

```
i  j  k
-------
1  2  3   will be checked
1  3  2   will be checked
2  1  3   will be checked
2  3  1   will be checked
3  1  2   will be checked
3  2  1   will be checked
```

So you check the same triplet 6 times. That's not what you want (I assume).

Instead consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  system("cls");
  int count = 0;
  int arr[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
 
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    for (int j = i+1; j < 8; j++)
    {
      for (int k = j+1; k < 8; k++)
      {
        if (arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k] == 12)
        {
          count = count + 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  printf("Count=%d", count);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: hmm I know the solution, I'm wondering why it works. Visualizing 3d loops doesn't seem easy thing to do either. Why does this i+1,j+1 makes things tick?

Comment: @usedmoney because it ensures that you always look at 3 different array elements